# @ContentChildren returns empty list, if content passed through 2 components

Tags: angular, angular2-decorators

I have next structure:

Child component template (it's the simplest):

```
   <div>Child</div>
```

Parent component template:

```
  <div><h1>Parent</h1>
    <middle>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </middle>
  </div>
```

And as you can see we have one more in the middle,
Middle Component templtate:

```
  <div>
    <h1>Middle</h1>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
```

And I am using next way:

```
  <parent>
      <child>hi</child>
      <child>there</child>
  </parent>
```

**Problem**: I couldn't get ContentChildren of Child components in Middle component?

Should angular2 support it? If not, then why?

[Plnkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bMNFvwz0eQwjSIxBnvE8?p=preview) - see output in console

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I am ready to clarify it, just ask questions. You could also look demo, open console and check it out put: 
for Parent component - I am getting 2 element in QueryList,
but for Middle - 0, whether I expected to see the same 2 components

Comment: so what should be the count of each ??

Comment: I expected to see 2 Child components  in both cases since they are the same

Comment: why are you using this way?

Comment: I am creating component, which has a bit more complected logic, that component I've introduced in demo. So I just want to split responsibilities between 2 components. Since  my "Parent" component become big enough, I am going to move some logic into "Middle" component.
And seems it's not a good place to discuss why I am using it, let's better try to understand why it's not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137717/discussion-between-aravind-and-ilyabasiuk).

Answer (score 2):

> [descendants](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren) - True to include all descendants, otherwise include only
>   direct children.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    directives: [ Middle],
    template: `<div><h1>Parent</h1>
        <middle>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </middle>
      </div>`
})
export class Parent {
    @ContentChildren(Child, { descendants: true }) children: QueryList<Child>;
    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log(this.children.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no content-children in `Middle`, they are passed right through to the outermost `<ng-content>`.

If you pass a `Child` in `Parent` as child of `Middle`, you get a contentchild in middle.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1kDbKzBfUiRFuR4DxkKV?p=preview)

You could use selectors in `<ng-content select="...">` to specify which elements should be projected to which `<ng-content>`

Comment: But does it look for you like a right behavior? Is there any information in documentation about it?

Comment: Yes. ng-content just passes along. That last catches. I don't know about specific documentation about that, just from discussions in GitHub issues.

Comment: Could you give me some links to Github issues, where I could read more about it?

Comment: Sorry, don't remember where this was mentioned. I'm following since 1.5 years.